# Не срабатывает os.listdir(path=".")

Tags: python

Прописываю в Python (3.4.4):

```
os.listdir(path=".")
```

но ничего не происходит.

Что я не так делаю?

Comment: А что, по Вашему мнению, должно происходить? Попробуйте, к примеру `print(os.listdir('.'))`.

Comment: Очень благодарен print(os.listdir('.')) сработало , когда читал инструкцию и скопировал на другом форуми не черта не получилась .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ответ из комментария:

---

А что, по Вашему мнению, должно происходить? Попробуйте, к примеру

```
print(os.listdir('.'))
```

Comment: Спасибо уже разобрался )